# How to determine $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(5k+1)^{2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there way to determine this sum below?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(5k+1)^{2}}$$

I mean, we can find the approximate value of it. But is there any chance to write this with known constants like \pi or values of riemann zeta function. Or can we do a transformation of this sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer. You can convert it in an integral form by using the identity
$$
(1+x)^{-\gamma}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\gamma)}\int_0^\infty d\xi\ e^{-\xi}\xi^{\gamma-1}e^{-\xi x}\ .
$$Apply it to $x=5k$ and $\gamma=2$, and obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(5k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\int_0^\infty d\xi\ e^{-\xi}\xi\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-5 k \xi}=\int_0^\infty d\xi\ \frac{\xi e^{4\xi}}{e^{5\xi}-1}\ ,$$
where one computes a simple geometric series.
The integral should be computable with elementary means, and the result is $(1/25)\psi^{(1)}(1/5)\approx 1.0507...$ [Polygamma function].

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, if I may propose $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{(5k+1)^{2}}=\frac{1}{25}\,\Phi \left(x,2,\frac{1}{5}\right)$$where appears  the [Lerch transcendent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function).

Now $$\Phi \left(1,2,\frac{1}{5}\right)=\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{5}\right)=\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$$where appear the [generalized Riemann function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) and/ot the digamma function.